# How can I write an Excel formula that will match two columns of data against another table, and only return true if both columns match?

Tags: excel-formula

I want to be able to tell if a row in my working table matches another table. Specifically, I only want to know if both values from two columns match.

For example, if `james@abc.com` has a source of `leadgen` in both tables, that's a match. Here are some example tables to illustrate that.

**My working table**

```
| Email         | Source  |
|---------------|---------|
| james@abc.com | leadgen | Matched!
| mike@abc.com  | leadgen | No Match
| billy@abc.com | leadgen | No Match
| amy@abc.com   | leadgen | No Match
```

**Table I want to match against**

```
| Email         | Source  |
|---------------|---------|
| james@abc.com | leadgen |
| mike@abc.com  | popup   |
| amy@abc.com   | banner  |
```

Here is the formula I tried using.

`IF(AND(
        MATCH([Email],'secondTable[Email],0),
        MATCH([Source],'secondTable[Source],0)), 
    "Matched!","No Match"`

Unfortunately, this returns a match for `mike@abc.com` because even though his source is `popup` in the second table, the source value `leadgen` appears elsewhere. At least that's what I'm interpreting here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `COUNTIFS`:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(secondTable[Source],[Source], secondTable[Email], [Email]),"Matched!","No Match")
```

Comment: Yeah whatever, go the simple route. 8P

Comment: @ScottCraner sometimes we think of it too much so we we dont see the simple solution :)

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(ISNUMERIC(MATCH([Email]&[Source],secondTable[Email]&secondTable[Source],0)),"Matched!","No Match")
```

Confirm with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when leaving edit mode.